# WPF conversion file from base64 and assignment source - c#

Tags: c#, json, wpf, file, base64

I gather from json files that the user clicks on a wpf list ( c # ) .
Click to call a json pass me the file content in Base64 . I would convert it and have it displayed immediately without writing it on the user's hard .

And ' possible to convert it and leave it on the ram can then see immediately , as well as assign it to the object's source imageViewer?

Thank you

```
   <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Thin}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#007AFF" Text="{x:Static res:strings.indietroPage}" MouseDown="GoBackFrame_MouseDown" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding uriImageSource}" Name="imageViewer"></Image>
        </Grid>
```

first I was saving to disk first and then visualized , but I need that is not saved to disk , and you receive immediately as Source

```
File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + attachmentDownload.Name + "." + attachmentDownload.Extension, Convert.FromBase64String(attachmentDownload.B64Content));
```

i have try this

```
fileSourceBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(attachmentDownload.B64Content);
                    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                    bi.BeginInit();
                    bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(fileSourceBytes);
                    bi.EndInit();

                    imageViewer.Source = bi;
```

but receive an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which object instance is null, when you are getting the error?

Comment: imageViewer is null, but is in xaml

Comment: Your ImageViewer control is not initialized yet than. Please make sure your `InitializeComponent()` method in the Window's/UserControl's codebehind is being called before you are trying to set that' `Source` property. (And also make sure that the control with `"imageViewer"` name attribute is exists.)

Answer (score 0):

solution:
codebehind

```
public Byte[] fileSourceBytes { get; set; }    
fileSourceBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(attachmentDownload.B64Content);
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(fileSourceBytes);
bi.EndInit();

uriImageSource = bi;
```

xaml:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding uriImageSource}" Name="imageViewer"></Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best solution would be if you would just bind the `BitmapImage` to the `ImageViewer's Source` property.

ViewModel:

```
BitmapImage _imageViewerSource;

public BitmapImage ImageViewerSource {
    get { return _imageViewerSource; }
    private set
    { 
        _imageViewerSource = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ImageViewerSource"); // or OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageViewerSource)); if you are using VS2015+
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageViewerSource, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem issue

```
using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
    {
        writer.WriteBytes(Convert.FromBase64String(base64););
        writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
    }

    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(stream);
}
```